# Executing copy of the method always gives 2x performance

Tags: .net, performance, .net-core

I have written next test program in .Net Core 2.2 and executing it on 3 different PC gives roughly same result: second executing method always executes faster.

The code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            RunTest();
        }
    }

    private static void RunTest()
    {
        const long cnt = 1000000000;

        var time1 = Test1(cnt);
        var time2 = Test2(cnt);

        Console.WriteLine($"Done in: {time1} vs {time2} diff: {time1 - time2}");
    }

    private static TimeSpan Test1(long cnt)
    {
        var v = 1;
        var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (long i = cnt; i != 0; i--)
        {
            v = RotateBit(v);
        }
        timer.Stop();

        return timer.Elapsed;
    }

    private static TimeSpan Test2(long cnt)
    {
        var v = 1;
        var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (long i = cnt; i != 0; i--)
        {
            v = RotateBit(v);
        }
        timer.Stop();

        return timer.Elapsed;
    }

    private static int RotateBit(int v)
    {
        v = v << 1;

        if ((v & 0b0000_1111) == 0)
        {
            v = 1;
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

Please note that `Test1` and `Test2` methods are absolute copy.
No meter which is first `Test1` or `Test2`, the one executed that is executed first always almost 2 time faster: `Done in: 00:00:00.8881566 vs 00:00:00.4706360 diff: 00:00:00.4175206` even though `RunTest` method is executed multiple times.

What could be the reason for such a strange behavior?

Comment: Interesting - I see this (not quite as much, but still significantly) for `netcoreapp2.2` but not `netcoreapp2.1`.

Comment: Could be warmup, could be JIT. Bit shifting and masking are two of the fastest CPU operations and easy to parallelize and predict. This means simple benchmarking like this isn't very useful. I'd use BenchmarkDotNet to get better measurements but I wouldn't expect the results to be very reliable

Comment: I'm not sure that we can trust these simple benchmarks. Could you measure that with something like [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/index.html)?

Comment: With BenchmarkDotNet I got the same result's. But that's I still wonder why am I receiving 2x difference in the initial test.

Comment: BTW, I've made more tests, and noticed that difference correlate with number of 1 inside `if` statement: `if ((v & 0b0000_1111) == 0)` the more 1 the lower difference.
Looks like Branch predictor, but why it's only affects `Test1` and not `Test2`?

Comment: I think it was a bug. Now shows same results in .net core sdk 2.1 and 2.2. download latest version and check again.

Comment: Profiling such extremely fast code is a perilous affair.  Add Console.Write(string.Empty); to the top of Test1() and it will speed up and make the difference disappear.  All that it really does is make the branch target addresses different, making branch prediction behave different.

Comment: @Hans Passant. That make it even more interesting! Could you please explain why `Console.Write(string.Empty)` speeds up the method? And also explain why without it it gives such a big difference?

Comment: There is not much to explain beyond what I already commented, code execution on modern CPU cores is not deterministic.  On my machine the difference is only a single CPU cycle.  Your test multiplies that by a billion.  Sure, now you can see that.  Don't focus on a single cycle.

Comment: You run them after another. Do you get the same result if both calls are to Test1? Maybe it's a warm up thing? or some intelligence that the CPU? notices a pattern in your calls. Have you warmed up beforehand or is the first call the first call? Whatever the first call does it might allocate memory that future calls reuse.